# config fstab file for a diefferent partition root directories

Tags: fstab

I have copied my `/var /opt /usr` directories to a newpartititon and now I need to configure the `fstab` file.

That is the new partition content:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Dec 20 12:16 opt
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Dec  8 06:52 usr
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Dec 21 08:35 var
```

This is how I want to change the `fstab` file:

```
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
tmpfs       /tmp    tmpfs   nodev,nosuid    0   0
UUID=00e31411-0730-9903-c038-45c4014ce600 / ext2 defaults 0 1
UUID=4bbbd587-1439-427b-9584-5b36d904f4c3 /home ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=5a694838-c110-4eb9-9703-c490792af400 swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=7502c4a6-f13b-40e7-ab3c-aaaa630d6b4d /var
UUID=7502c4a6-f13b-40e7-ab3c-aaaa630d6b4d /opt
UUID=7502c4a6-f13b-40e7-ab3c-aaaa630d6b4d /usr
```

Will the `fstab` file detect the subdirectories in each partition or should I put each directory in its own partition?

Since in my `/home` partition, there is the home's contents and not another home directory, I think that the above configuration wouldn't work, since in the new partition i have three separate directories.

What you think is the best way to do that via one partition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `mount` does not "detect" any directories under a filesystem. It is not its purpose.

If you put `/var`, `/opt` and `/usr` all on a one partition, which is *not* the root partition of your system, you'll need to do two things:

1. Mount the partition under some separate, special directory - let's say `/mnt/sysdirs`
2. **Bind-mount** the directories at their proper places in the root filesystem.

So the `fstab` in your case should look something like this:

```
tmpfs       /tmp    tmpfs   nodev,nosuid    0   0
UUID=00e31411-0730-9903-c038-45c4014ce600 / ext2 defaults 1 1
UUID=4bbbd587-1439-427b-9584-5b36d904f4c3 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
UUID=5a694838-c110-4eb9-9703-c490792af400 swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=7502c4a6-f13b-40e7-ab3c-aaaa630d6b4d /mnt/sysdirs ext4 defaults 0 0
/mnt/sysdirs/opt   /opt  none bind,rw 0 0 
/mnt/sysdirs/usr   /usr  none bind,rw 0 0
/mnt/sysdirs/var   /var  none bind,rw 0 0
```