# Ubuntu install spanning multiple disks

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

Having to reinstall the operative system from scratch on an EeePC 901, which has two SSD disks, 4GB and 16GB, is it possible to install it using both disks as if they were one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Logical Volume Manager will do this for you... I have never tried it on SSD's but I don't see why it would not work.

install command

```
"apt-get install lvm2"
```

Here is the user guide. http://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager

Comment: I will read your link carefully, but could you please elaborate a bit? I have never done something different from a standard install until now.. How can I install programs if I am on a live USB?

Comment: You would install on the larger volume, then expand it to consume all the available space.... To be honest if it was me I would not do this.... I would install the OS and the larger disk and mount the smaller one to /home.

Comment: That would be an option too, I always installed it the other way around, by then enabling compression on the smaller disk.

Comment: well if you do this, you will not lose all your personal data (on the 4GB drive) when you reinstall the OS in the future (on the larger drive)... this is a common practice, especially if you like trying out other flavors of linux.

Comment: one issue here is that the 4GB drive is faster, so you wouldn't want to install onto the larger drive

Comment: Ahh... that is a good point. In that case I think I agree with TooTone, go try some other distros that are lighter. there are lots  of Debian/*buntu based distros that will fit on 4gb easily. I am not sure LVM will span the 2 disks well in that case either....

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly answering your question but you might want to consider finding an o/s you *can* easily install on the main 4GB partition. You ought to be able to move parts of the o/s if necessary onto the larger, slower partition (using `fstab`, see, e.g., [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27434/58126)). I have an eee 901, which ran out of steam on the original ubuntu eee o/s I'd installed.

I spent a long time researching a system which would fit on 4GB, and ended up with peppermint os three. It's [based on lubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppermint_Linux_OS) so should seem familiar to an ubuntu user.

Basically, it just doesn't have all the bloat so fits on 4GB. I've installed libre office, vlc, chrome (from which I'm writing this) and a bunch of other stuff and am still under 4GB (87% usage). The system feels like it's had new life breathed into it -- I've been really pleased. On the other hand I wouldn't want to run any more heavyweight desktop manager on the eee, certainly not unity or the latest gnome.

Once you have a system installed, if you run out of space I think you ought to be able to move parts of the system onto the other partition. And of course you could even install other desktops if you don't like the default.

I see [peppermint four](http://peppermintos.com/guide/downloading/) is now out, which says it will install on 2GB but recommends 4GB.

(The only issue I had when installing peppermint was the same one I had with several ubuntu based linux distros when installing on a machine with multiple partitions. Grub got confused and wasn't installed properly and I had to go back in and do some magic to get it to work properly and be able to boot. I may have some notes somewhere so comments if you try peppermint and hit this...)

Comment: I must say that my eeePC currently has ubuntu 12.04 installed, but I need to reinstall from scratch after my sister did some damage I am unable to identify... I will consider your suggestion, though!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I wasn't clear what you were asking then. Clearly if you have installed 12.04 in the past, you can do it again, so what is the problem you have? Is your question what happens when you run out of space on the 4GB partition? Or is it can you install without compression across both drives? Or something else?

Comment: The problem is that 4 GB might be too little without compression, but I would want to remove it since it slows things down. Also, wouldn't it be "simpler" for the OS if it looked like it was installed on a single 20GB disk?

Comment: I see where you're coming from now. Personally I think it's _less_ simple to add another layer using LVM, especially as you'd prefer to keep the o/s on the 4GB partition for speed as far as is possible. I would go with installing something on the 4GB partition (minimal ubuntu 12.04, or lightweight ubuntu derivative as I suggested), and then when you run out of space copy parts of the root filesystem onto the other partition and then change fstab to point to the copy and delete on the 4GB partition.

Comment: Yes, but with my ideal setup, I wouldn't have to worry for free space anymore, at least up to those (in)famous 20GB.

Comment: well you pays your money and you takes your chances. The nice thing about playing with linux is that _you_ get to decide what's important and the best way to solve it for your needs. Good luck either way!